# Substitution of sequences to derive recursive mean

Tags: recursion, difference-equations, algebra

I would have the following derivation to calculate the recursive moving average and I'd like to follow it as closely as possible in Mathematica.

For the sequence where $y(i)$ is considered as an observation of a at the ith instant:

$y(i) = a + e(i); i = 1,2,...,N$

The mean of the entire sequence is $\widetilde{a}$:

$\widetilde{a}(k) = \frac{1}{k}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}{y(i)}$

At for the $(k - 1)^{th}$ instant:

$\widetilde{a}(k-1)=\frac{1}{k-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}{y(i)}$

I am trying to use Mathematica to rearrange the above equations to obtain the following equation for the recursive mean:

$\widetilde{a}(k) = \widetilde{a}(k-1)+\frac{1}{k}[y(k)-\widetilde{a}(k-1)]$

I have the definitions of for each of the expressions:

```
OverTilde[a][k_, y_] := (1/k) Sum[y[i], { i, 1, k}]
eq1 = OverTilde[a][k, y]
eq2 = OverTilde[a][k - 1, y]
```

How do I substitute eq1 into eq2 in order to obtain the equation for the recursive mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematica currently has a gap in its sum functionality, but it is still possible to verify the recursive mean identity. Here is the code:

```
OverTilde[a][k_, y_] := (1/k) Sum[y[i], {i, 1, k}];
eq1 = OverTilde[a][k, y];
eq2 = OverTilde[a][k - 1, y];
rule = Sum[x_[j_], {j_, a_, b_}] :> x[b] + Sum[x[j], {j, a, b - 1}];
(eq1 /. rule) == eq2 + (y[k] - eq2)/k // Simplify
```

which returns `True`. The reason for `rule` is that Mathematica currently
can not do this automatically.